WaitHoldingLocks Exception
[libart.so] art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks
ANR triggered by thread waiting for a binder transaction     
 *emphasized text* "main" tid=1 Native
  #00  pc 0x0000000000099ccc  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (syscall+28)
  #01  pc 0x000000000023247c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks+140)
  #02  pc 0x000000000045b218  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (artJniMethodEnd+336)
  #03  pc 0x00000000005bf0fc  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_jni_method_end+12)
  at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative (Native method)
  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact (BinderProxy.java:685)
  at android.app.job.IJobCallback$Stub$Proxy.acknowledgeStartMessage (IJobCallback.java:434)
  at android.app.job.JobServiceEngine$JobHandler.ackStartMessage (JobServiceEngine.java:384)
  at android.app.job.JobServiceEngine$JobHandler.handleMessage (JobServiceEngine.java:196)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:257)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:368)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8839)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:572)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1049)

I've searched a couple of related issue just like this ANR exception I'm getting, like this one but it's obvious in its stacktrace what causes it, I'm not sure where to find the part that causes this issue, and it's something related to JobServiceEngine
Any ideas?

Can you share your JobService implementation?

@OluwafemiSule   That's what I'm trying to figure out since I don't find any explicit usage of JobServiceEngine, or any of those related classes below BinderProxy.transact() stacktrace

Did you read this by any chance?

@gtxtreme yes, I read the section that describes this type of stacktrace wherein just below BinderProxy.transact() is the root cause of the issue, all reports just came in on Android 14 users, my attempt to fix this as of the moment is upgrading Firebase SDKs.
